# seteer und Getter conflict with default constructor

Tags: constructor, setter

i write a c++ Code contain two clases and one derived class from both simultaneouously
in main funktion i have an object from the derived class declared with no constructor because i have already declared a default constructor in the base classes and those will be inhereted in the derived class without problem, then a tried to modify the member variable through setter functions that i have declared in the base clases this also should from my point of wiew implemented without problem. the problem is when i try to execute the Programm it will be excuted as i dont declare setter functions  the default constructor hier has the priority and will be excute again what should i do i want modify the memeber variables through setter

Comment: code and error message please.

Comment: i tried to pase the code it dosent work its long , i have no error my question is why when i try to ececute the code why the default constructor will be executed instead of the setter function

Comment: Simplify your code to reproduce the problem, then post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.